# how to make code implementation each day on clock 2:00 pm

Tags: swift

i am written this code, already run ,but it run randomly , i am need sync in specific time each day in backgrounde or active or inactive

**Required  : allow  code implementation just once  clock 2:00 pm in day**

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(86400)
}



func UploadJSON(completion: ((Bool,Error?) -> Void )? = nil) {

        let data:String = "test sync"
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "my Url")! as URL)
        let dataToUpload = data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let uploadTask = session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: dataToUpload,completionHandler: { (responseData, response, error) in
            // Check on some response headers (if it's HTTP)
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200..<300:
                    print("Success")
                case 400..<500:
                    print("Request error")
                case 500..<600:
                    print("Server error")
                case let otherCode:
                    print("Other code: \(otherCode)")
                }
            }

            // Do something with the response data
            if let
                responseData = responseData,
                let responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                print("Server Response:")
                print(responseString)
            }

            // Do something with the error
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion?(false, error)
            }
        })

        uploadTask.resume()


    }



func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        downloadJSON() { (newData,error) in
            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Failed")
                completionHandler(.failed)
            } else {
                NSLog("success")
                completionHandler(.newData)

            }
        }


    }
```

There is no error in the code, but does not work at a specific time but works randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background fetch cannot be run on a specific schedule, iOS determines when and how often your app gets an opportunity to run background fetch.

You could try scheduling local [silent notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) or even remote ones to trigger this each day.

[Schedule iOS local notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)

Comment: Can you explain more details about "You could try scheduling local silent notifications or even remote ones to trigger this each day.

"

Comment: I added a link in the answer which should help explain it

Comment: I added, it works fine but does not upload data to the server

Comment: You may need to raise a new question about that, post the code and explain how its all configured and explain the issue

Comment: you can see my quastion  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427738/how-to-upload-data-with-run-schedule-notification-in-swift